# How to use spark load multiple files from hdfs

Tags: apache-spark

I try to use the following code to load multiple files from HDFS:

```
val data = spark
.read
.option("header", "true")
.option("mergeSchema","true")
.format("parquet")
.load("data/day=1/att=2/*,data/day=1/att=3/*,data/day=1/att=4/*")
```

The I get a exception:

```
    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Path does not exist: hdfs://user/ccc/data/day=1/att=2/*,data/day=1/att=3/*,data/day=1/att=4/*
```

How can load multiple files from hdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose each of the file names in quotes individually. The following should work:

```
val data = spark
.read
.option("header", "true")
.option("mergeSchema","true")
.format("parquet")
.load("data/day=1/att=2/*","data/day=1/att=3/*","data/day=1/att=4/*")
```